# Custom Error Handler Returns A Different Error Than The Generic Error Handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

My custom error handler returns:

> **Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.**
>
> Source: System.Web
>
> Stack Track: at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e) at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at
>   ASP.inc_iframe_eventdetail_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in
>   c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\c30f285f\68ea8ff1\App_Web_g4uza9zi.4.cs:line 0 at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>
> Target Site: Boolean HandleError(System.Exception)

However, the generic error handler returns:

> **Server Error in '/' Application. Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key
>   constraints.**  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack
>   trace for more information about the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.ConstraintException: Failed to enable
>   constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null,
>   unique, or foreign-key constraints.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 44: ChurchEventDataSource.SelectParameters.Add("ChurchEventId",
>   Request.QueryString["EventId"]); Line 45: Line 46:
>   EventFormView.DataBind(); Line 47: break; Line 48:
>
> Source File:
>   c:\Sites\Altruistic\ChurchFinder\Inc\Iframe\EventDetail.aspx.cs Line:
>   46

Obviously, I want the most detailed description possible.

Comment: Which is the _code_  of ***custom error handler*** and ***generic error handler*** ? `Global.asax Application_Error` ? and  your **web.config** about `customerrors` and `httperrors` *sections* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your custom error handler & how are you retrieving the exception. Most probably you might be using `HttpServerUtility.GetLastError` method to get the exception - so in such case use `InnerException` property (if not null) of the actual exception object - it will have the actual exception that has occured.

Comment: Close, I'm using Server.GetLastError in my Global.asax, but the InnerException property *almost always* returns an HttpUnhandledException when just about any error occurs.

Comment: Ahh....figured it out. I was using .Message when I should have been using .InnerException. :| Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.